# how to get loop JSON value amount with random value array use PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, random

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "return": {
    "1400151861513776": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 138959.22155687,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556464987",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151861456538": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 4115.53246448,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556463520",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151861402138": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 252.29423504,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556462106",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151861205651": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 5735.02289537,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556457111",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151861064946": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 608.2294235,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556453555",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151860984352": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 13553.51532229,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556451515",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151860967764": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 49475.62404601,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556451103",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151860901030": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 21474.82564282,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556449399",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151860889146": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 2657.50733826,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556449090",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151860484795": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 71933.21911691,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556438570",
      "status": 0
    },
    "2400151859280443": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "sell",
      "amount": 266054.68380596,
      "rate": 0.00000088,
      "timestamp_created": "1556408217",
      "status": 0
    },
    "2400151857916444": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "sell",
      "amount": 400000,
      "rate": 0.0000009,
      "timestamp_created": "1556374931",
      "status": 0
    },
    "2400151857916059": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "sell",
      "amount": 400000,
      "rate": 0.00000089,
      "timestamp_created": "1556374923",
      "status": 0
    }
  }
}
```

how to get loop value amount..this array has random value 1400151861513776..change everytime..

i use php code.. `json_decode`..

Comment: `forEach` Maybe?

Comment: Please use `json_decode($yourJson, true)` and then loop through this array using `foreach($array as $key => $value)` where `$key` will containt that `1400151861513776 ` numbers.

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: how to get key only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `json_decode` to convert JSON to an array. [PHP json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

   ```
   $jsonToArray = json_decode($json,true); // $json has the `JSON`
   ```
2. If you need the `key` with the `amount` you can use `array_walk` [PHP array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

   ```
   $jsonToArray = json_decode($json,true);
   $res = [];
   array_walk($jsonToArray['return'], function($v, $k) use (&$res){
     $res[$k] = $v['amount'];
   });
   ```

Output:-

```
Array
(
  [1400151861513776] => 138959.22155687
  [1400151861456538] => 4115.53246448
   .......
   .......
  [2400151857916444] => 400000
  [2400151857916059] => 400000
)
```

OR

If you don't need `key`, only the `amount` you can use `array_map` [PHP array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$jsonToArray = json_decode($json,true);
$res = [];
array_map(function($v) use(&$res){
  $res[] = $v['amount'];
}, $jsonToArray['return']);
```

Output :-

```
 Array
(
  [0] => 138959.22155687
  [1] => 4115.53246448
   .......
   .......
)
```

Comment: how to get key only?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps mentioned to get the required data.

**Step 1: Make your data a valid JSON string**

```
$json_string = '{
  "success": 1,
  "return": {
    "1400151861513776": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 138959.22155687,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556464987",
      "status": 0
    },
    "1400151861456538": {
      "pair": "edc_btc",
      "type": "buy",
      "amount": 4115.53246448,
      "rate": 0.00000085,
      "timestamp_created": "1556463520",
      "status": 0
    }
  }
}';
```

Here I have wrapped your data in single quote to make it a valid JSON string

**Step 2: Use json_decode function to decode the JSON string**

```
$decoded_data = json_decode($json_string, $assoc=true);
```

When using the **json_decode** function, please make sure to set **$assoc** flag to **true**. Else it will return an object instead of an associative array.

**Step 3: Select the data on which you need to loop on**

```
$selected_data = $decoded_data["return"];
```

In this case its the **return** key in the decoded JSON.

**Step 4: Loop over the selected data to obtain the key and values**

```
foreach($selected_data as $key=>$value) {
  var_dump($key); # random value like 1400151861513776
}
```

$**key** will be holding the random value like **1400151861513776** and $**value** will be holding the data inside that key